# Iterating over a multiple sequences from a FASTA file to get the greatest ORF length

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I've written code for iterating over a FASTA file which works fine, yet I'm getting wrong lengths. I can't figure out how to modify the rest of the code so that it would yield the greatest ORF from every sequence, so that all the ORFs can be listed and then sorted to get the greatest length.

The code needs to return the length of the longest ORF only from the second reading frame, and only in the 3'->5' direction.

After using `translate()` to get the amino acids sequences from the DNA sequences, I used `len(pro)*3+3` to get the ORFs lengths. I also tried `translate()` with different arguments. Still got wrong results. I don't know what wrong with the code. A link to the file with the sequences can be found below the following code and output.

**The code**

```
from Bio import SeqIO
records = list(SeqIO.parse(r"file.fasta", "fasta"))
lengths = []
for record in records:
    table = 1
    min_pro_len = 100
    frame = 1
    longest = 0
    for strand, nuc in [(+1, record.seq)]:
        length = 3 * ((len(record)-frame) // 3) #Multiple of three
        for pro in nuc[frame:frame+length].translate(table).split("*"):
            if len(pro) >= min_pro_len and frame == 1:
                lengths.append(len(pro)*3+3)
```

**The output I'm getting**

When typing `>>> print(sorted(lengths))` in the Python shell, the following output is printed:

```
[303, 303, 306, 318, 339, 372, 384, 426, 429, 456, 471, 480, 489, 492, 546, 549, 570, 573, 576, 585, 660, 666, 684, 693, 810, 855, 945, 957, 1026, 1041, 1299, 1320, 1533, 1578, 1740, 1911]
```

**FASTA file with the sequences:**
[sequences.fasta](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14qEk3TTADucjlCG1eaeoemsrKlbA0DU-)

Comment: None of the lengths I'm getting appears as a correct answer in a course I'm taking.

Comment: Can you provide minimal example input data and the expected output, along with your current output? This will make your problem reproducible and easier for us to help you.

Comment: Sure. In a minute.

Comment: Oops. Just saw that you asked for the output. In a few more minutes.

Comment: Do you also have the expected output, i.e. the correct answer according to your course?

Comment: Only the possible answers to choose from.

Comment: One error I can see is that your code gives you only ORFs on the forward strand starting at the same nucleotide. You don’t really need to use the `translate` function here — just search for the regular expression `ATG(...)+(TAG|TAA|TGA)` — but be sure to search for *overlapping* matches (`re.findall` etc. only find non-overlapping matches), and then check which of these hits start in the second reading frame.

Comment: I'm starting at a specific nucleotide to get the 2nd reading frame.

Comment: You're suggesting that I'd use re.finditer() instead of re.findall()?

Comment: @it'sme No, `finditer` also doesn’t find overlapping matches, as its documentation clearly states. You need to manually call `re.search` with increasing start positions in a loop.

Comment: change lengths.append(len(pro)*3+3) with lengths.append(len(pro))

Comment: change for pro in nuc[frame:frame+length].translate(table).split("*"): with pro = max(nuc[frame:frame+length].translate(table).split("*"))

Answer (score 0):

can't find your original input anymore (link is empty).

Here my effort, not sure it's the correct one just check it with your input or try to have a look at my test input 'file.fasta_2':

```
>pippo
ATGAAACGTATGATGCGG
>pippo_2
AATGAAACGTATGATGCGG
>pippo_3
AGGCGCGCTTATATGCGGGCCTG
>pippo_4
AGGCGCGCTTATATGCGGGCCTGAGGCGCGCTTATATGCGGGCCTG
>pippo_5
AGGCGCGCTTATATGCGGATGATGGCCTGAGGCGCGCTTATATGCGGGCCTGATGATGATGTATTTATT
```

code is :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed May  5 18:04:04 2021

@author: Pietro

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61229690/iterating-over-a-multiple-sequences-from-a-fasta-file-to-get-the-greatest-orf-le



seq.translate doesnt look for first ATG
The code needs to return the length of the longest ORF only from the second reading frame, and only in the 3'->5' direction.


"""

from Bio import SeqIO



records = list(SeqIO.parse(r"file.fasta_2", "fasta"))

print(records)



lengths = []
for record in records:
    table = 1
    # min_pro_len = 100
    min_pro_len = 3
    frame = 1
    longest = 0
    for strand, nuc in [(+1, record.seq)]:
        length = 3 * ((len(record)-frame) // 3) #Multiple of three
        print(length)
        print(nuc[frame:frame+length].translate(table).split("*"))
        pro = max(nuc[frame:frame+length].translate(table).split("*"))
        print(pro)
            
        if len(pro) >= min_pro_len and frame == 1:
            
                lengths.append([str(pro),len(pro), record.name])




print(sorted(lengths, key=lambda tup: tup[1]))
```

output is:

```
[['MKRMMR', 6, 'pippo_2'], ['GALICGP', 7, 'pippo_3'], ['GALICGPEARLYAGL', 15, 'pippo_4'], ['WPEARLYAGLMMMYL', 15, 'pippo_5']]
```